# How to let a set in C++ filter out the different pointers pointing to the same value

Tags: c++, pointers, set

As we know, C++ "set" will not allow the same values being inserted.

My question is, how can I apply this to a bunch of pointers, where some of them will point to the same value.
Let's just move on to the following example

```
set<int *> my_set;
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 10;
int *ptr1 = &a, *ptr2 = &b, *ptr3 = &c;
my_set.insert(ptr1);  // Insert successfully
my_set.insert(ptr2);  // Insert successfully
my_set.insert(ptr3);  // Although insert successfully, 
                      // BUT I DON'T WANT ptr3 TO BE INSERTED,
                      // since it points to the same value as ptr1 does
```

Except checking the contained values one by one, like inserting after iteratively checking the set via a for-loop, are there any ways for me to do what I just mentioned above?

Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Did You try to add a custom comparer?

Comment: Use `std::map<int, int*>` instead, so when the key is found "the value of the pointer in your case" just ignore inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by using a `std::set` with a custom comparator that compares the values that each pointer is pointing to. `std::set` has a 2nd optional template parameter that specifies a custom class that's used for comparing values in the set. Normally it's `std::less`, i.e., a fancy facade for the `<` operator. Basically, just specify a custom comparator that defines what `<` means for the values in your set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct comparator {

    bool operator()(int * const &a,
            int * const &b) const
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<int *, comparator> my_set;

    int a = 10, b = 20, c = 10;
    int *ptr1 = &a, *ptr2 = &b, *ptr3 = &c;
    my_set.insert(ptr1);
    my_set.insert(ptr2);
    my_set.insert(ptr3);

    for (const auto &p: my_set)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy Molly, just that simple? R U telling me that if the comparator finds the two values are the same, the second one will be ignored? Is it what u r indicating here?

Comment: The job of the comparator is to define what `<` means for the values in a `std::set`. That's it. End of story. `std::set` does everything else based on this. Attempting to insert something that "already exists" in a set always gets ignored. Whether it's a set of `int`s, or a set of some values for which a comparator defines what `<` means, in some fashion.

Comment: I've tried your codes, it actually works!! Thanks for your answer again!

Comment: And wait! I just want to ask another thing u've said. How do a set define "already exists", your comparator only tells "If the first less ( or greater ) than the second one"

Comment: Now compare if the "second one" is less than the "first one". If both comparisons come up as "false" -- `a < b` is false and `b < a` is false; `std::set` concludes that the values must be equal.

Comment: Oh! U mean there is another reverse comparing going on beneath the table. OK, I get it! thx a lot